# How to use host machine local hard drive storage in minikube persistant volume

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, yaml, torrent

I have case with torrent client, where I need it to download files to /srv/downloads directory where /srv is my hard drive mount point. I know that minikube creates a vm for docker user, and only directories inside that vm are accessible. The workaround would be to use minikube mount command but according to official documentation:

> suffers from performance and reliability issues when used with large folders (>600 files)

Here are my yaml files:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.service.type: NodePort
    kompose.version: 1.26.0 (40646f47)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: qbittorrent
  name: qbittorrent
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: qbittorrent
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert
        kompose.service.type: NodePort
        kompose.version: 1.26.0 (40646f47)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
          io.kompose.service: qbittorrent
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: PGID
              value: "1000"
            - name: PUID
              value: "1000"
            - name: TZ
              value: Europe/London
            - name: WEBUI_PORT
              value: "8080"
          image: lscr.io/linuxserver/qbittorrent
          name: qbittorrent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6881
            - containerPort: 6881
              protocol: UDP
            - containerPort: 8080
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: srv/peer-box-config
              name: qbittorrent-claim1
            - mountPath: srv/downloads
              name: qbittorrent-claim0
      restartPolicy: Always
        volumes:
        - name: qbittorrent-claim0
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: qbittorrent-claim0
        - name: qbittorrent-claim1
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: qbittorrent-claim1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.service.type: NodePort
    kompose.version: 1.26.0 (40646f47)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: qbittorrent
  name: qbittorrent
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "6881"
      port: 6881
      targetPort: 6881
    - name: 6881-udp
      port: 6881
      protocol: UDP
      targetPort: 6881
    - name: "8080"
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: qbittorrent
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: hard-drive-config-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /srv/peer-box-config
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - minikube
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: hard-drive-downloads-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 12Ti
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: srv/downloads
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - minikube
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: qbittorrent-claim0
  name: qbittorrent-claim0
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: local-storage
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 12Ti
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: qbittorrent-claim1
  name: qbittorrent-claim1
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: local-storage
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
---
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

With this configuration the PVC's are bound and the /srv/downloads directory is present for the docker user, but the storage space is limited by /var directory, Which means it doesn't actually use the hard drive storage space.

Is it even possible for docker user to interact with host file system ? Also using the mount command everytime seems dumb. How could I specify this behaviour in PV/PVC yaml file ? Any suggestions on how should I proceed are welcome.

EDIT:

If you are trying to reproduce and access the dashboard first expose the port via ssh like this:

```
ssh -i ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa docker@$(minikube ip) -L \*:8080:0.0.0.0:{kubernetes node port < 30000}
```

Default credentials are admin:adminadmin, in the dashboard bottom right corner shows free storage available for the client

Comment: The [documentation you quote](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/#9p-mounts) says "**9P mounts** ... suffers ... See **Driver mounts** as an alternative."  If you create the PersistentVolume pointing at the right (driver/OS-specific) directory it may get around this.

Comment: "Is it possible for Docker user to interact with host file system?"  No, a specific design goal of Docker is that they can't without explicitly being given access.  And Kubernetes is designed for a multi-host cluster environment, so "host filesystem" usually means something different depending on which node a pod is running on; this minikube setup is an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @DavidMaze, but it seems I won't be able to use it because there are no [supported hostFolders](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/#driver-mounts) for my enviroment . What do you think if I setup my local system's /srv directory as NFS and use that to mount in persistent volumes. Would it introduce any latency or performance  downgrade compared to mounts ? Example here: http://pietervogelaar.nl/minikube-nfs-mounts [link](http://pietervogelaar.nl/minikube-nfs-mounts)